# genetic algorithm for classification and fitness evaluation

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I have been reading the Tom Mitchell book about Machine Learning the part of Genetic Algorithms for Classification. The example that they put is fairly simple, they say that if I have the following:

[image]

then the fitness function could be defined as:

[image]

I would like to apply this approach for the classification of the census-income data that has the following form:

```
39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
50, Self-emp-not-inc, 83311, Bachelors, 13, Married-civ-spouse, Exec-managerial, Husband, White, Male, 0, 0, 13, United-States, <=50K
38, Private, 215646, HS-grad, 9, Divorced, Handlers-cleaners, Not-in-family, White, Male, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
53, Private, 234721, 11th, 7, Married-civ-spouse, Handlers-cleaners, Husband, Black, Male, 0, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
28, Private, 338409, Bachelors, 13, Married-civ-spouse, Prof-specialty, Wife, Black, Female, 0, 0, 40, Cuba, <=50K
```

In this dataset the attributes are the following:

```
age: continuous.
workclass: Private, Self-emp-not-inc, Self-emp-inc, Federal-gov, Local-gov, State-gov, Without-pay, Never-worked.
fnlwgt: continuous.
education: Bachelors, Some-college, 11th, HS-grad, Prof-school, Assoc-acdm, Assoc-voc, 9th, 7th-8th, 12th, Masters, 1st-4th, 10th, Doctorate, 5th-6th, Preschool.
education-num: continuous.
marital-status: Married-civ-spouse, Divorced, Never-married, Separated, Widowed, Married-spouse-absent, Married-AF-spouse.
occupation: Tech-support, Craft-repair, Other-service, Sales, Exec-managerial, Prof-specialty, Handlers-cleaners, Machine-op-inspct, Adm-clerical, Farming-fishing, Transport-moving, Priv-house-serv, Protective-serv, Armed-Forces.
relationship: Wife, Own-child, Husband, Not-in-family, Other-relative, Unmarried.
race: White, Asian-Pac-Islander, Amer-Indian-Eskimo, Other, Black.
sex: Female, Male.
capital-gain: continuous.
capital-loss: continuous.
hours-per-week: continuous.
native-country
```

At the end what I want is to have a classifier that given some attributes could predict if the income of the person would be less or greater than 50000. How could I model the fitness function for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, for such purpose, the Genetic Programming is used. Here is a paper describing such scenario: http://web.cs.mun.ca/~banzhaf/papers/ieee_taec.pdf

If you are looking for a source code, you can use Tiny GP by ricardo poli: http://cswww.essex.ac.uk/staff/rpoli/TinyGP/ However, first of all you must transform all attributes to numerical values.

You can also use other GP variants. I did an implementation of Multi Expression Programming which is here: http://www.mepx.org/source_code.html